# How to fix animation script so that humanoid character holds their weapon

Tags: unity, c#, animation, shooter, third-person-view

[I am trying to follow this tutorial video about setting up an third-person shooter character in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qkqjL3xc24).

But my character will not hold their weapon. I'm also getting the following warnings in my project:

> Assets/Unity-1/unity-1/player/playerAnimation.cs(8, 23): warning CS0649: Field `playerAnimation.aimMask' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value.
>
> Assets/Unity-1/unity-1/player/playerAnimation.cs(16, 23): warning CS0414: The private field `playerAnimation.chestBone' is assigned but its value is never used.
>
> Assets/Unity-1/unity-1/player/playerLocomotion.cs(12, 19): warning CS0414: The private field `playerLocomotion.aimedWalkSpeed' is assigned but its value is never used.

[image: Unity editor screenshot showing warnings]

How can I fix this?

Here are the scripts that the warnings complain about:

Player Animation:

```
/// <license>
/// Copyright(c) 2020 www.GameDevine.com
/// </license>
///
using UnityEngine;

public class playerAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
   private LayerMask aimMask;
   private playerLocomotion playerLocomtion = null;
   private playerCamera playerCamera = null;
   private MovementCalculator movementCalculator = null;
   private playerWeapon playerWeapon = null;

   private Animator animator = null;
   [System.NonSerialized] public bool readyToMove = true;
   private Transform chestBone = null;
   [System.NonSerialized] public Vector3 trgetPoint = Vector3.zero;

   private float handIkSpeed = 10;
   private Transform rHandIk = null;
   private Transform lHandIk = null;
   private Transform rElbowIk = null;
   private Transform lElbowIk = null;


   private void Awake()
   {
      playerLocomtion = GetComponent<playerLocomotion>();
      playerCamera = GetComponent<playerCamera>();
      movementCalculator = GetComponent<MovementCalculator>();
      animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
      playerWeapon = GetComponent<playerWeapon>();
      rHandIk = new GameObject("rhik").transform;
      lHandIk = new GameObject("lhik").transform;
      rElbowIk = new GameObject("reik").transform;
      lElbowIk = new GameObject("leik").transform;
      Transform p = animator.GetBoneTransform(HumanBodyBones.Chest);
      rHandIk.parent = p;
      lHandIk.parent = p;
      rElbowIk.parent = p;
      lElbowIk.parent = p;
  }
  public void InitializeWeapon()
  {
     if(playerWeapon.weapon != null)
     {
        if (!rHandIk)
        {
           rHandIk = new GameObject("rhik").transform;
        }
        if (!lHandIk)
        {
           lHandIk = new GameObject("lhik").transform;
        }
        rHandIk.parent = playerWeapon.weapon.model;
        lHandIk.parent = playerWeapon.weapon.model;
     }
  }


  private void Update()
  {
     trgetPoint = GetAimTarget(50);
     animator.SetBool("Crouch", playerLocomtion.crouched);
     animator.SetBool("aimed" , playerLocomtion.aiming);
     animator.SetBool("grounded", playerLocomtion.grounded);
     animator.SetFloat("moveX", movementCalculator.Movement.x);
     animator.SetFloat("moveY", movementCalculator.Movement.z);
     switch (playerLocomtion.MoveType)
     {
         case 1:
               animator .SetBool("Walk" , true);
               animator .SetBool("Sprint", false);
               animator .SetBool("Run" , false);
               break;
         case 2:
               animator.SetBool("Walk" , false);
               animator.SetBool("Sprint", false);
               animator.SetBool("Run" , true);
               break;
         case 3:
               animator.SetBool("Walk" , false);
               animator.SetBool("Sprint", true);
               animator.SetBool("Run" , false);
               break;
         default:
              animator.SetBool("Walk" , false);
              animator.SetBool("Sprint", false);
              animator.SetBool("Run" , false);
              break;

       }
       readyToMove = !animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsTag("Transition");
    }
    private Vector3 GetAimTarget(float range)
    {
       Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2));
       ray.origin = playerCamera.pivot.position;
       RaycastHit hit;
       if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, range, aimMask))
       {
          return hit.point;

       }
       else
       {
          return playerCamera.pivot.position + playerCamera.main.forward.normalized * range;
       }

    }
 }
```

Player Locomotion:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;


public class playerLocomotion : MonoBehaviour
{
   private float walkSpeed = 4f;
   private float runSpeed = 7f;
   private float sprintSpeed = 10f;
   private float aimedWalkSpeed = 4f;
   private float crouchWalkSpeed = 3f;
   private float rotateSpeed = 10f;
   private float aimedRotateSpeed = 20;

   private playerCamera playerCamera = null;
   private playerinput playerinput = null;
   playerAnimation playerAnimation = null;
  [NonSerialized] public bool grounded = true;
   private float movement = 0f;
   private int moveType = 0;
  [NonSerialized] public bool crouched = false;
  [NonSerialized] public bool aiming = false;


   public int MoveType
   {
      get
      {
         if (movement < 0.1f)
         {
            return 0;
         }
         else
         {
           return moveType;
         }
     }
  }

  private void Awake()
  {
    playerCamera = GetComponent<playerCamera>();
    playerinput = GetComponent<playerinput>();
    playerAnimation = GetComponent<playerAnimation>();
  }

  private void Update()
  {
     float ver = playerinput.vertical;
     float hor = playerinput.horizontal;
     if (!playerAnimation.readyToMove)
     {
        ver = 0;
        hor = 0;

     }
     if(playerinput.crouch && grounded && !playerinput.sprint)
     {
       crouched = !crouched;
     }
     movement = Mathf.Clamp01(Mathf.Abs(hor) + Mathf.Abs(ver));
     if (grounded)
     {
        Vector3 cameraDirection = playerCamera.main.forward * ver;
        cameraDirection += playerCamera.main.right * hor;
        Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
        if (playerinput.jump)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            if (aiming)
            {

            }
            else
            {

 
               #region Rotation
               cameraDirection.Normalize();
               cameraDirection.y = 0;
               if(cameraDirection == Vector3.zero)
               {
                  cameraDirection = transform.forward;
               }
               Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.LookRotation(cameraDirection);
               Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion .Slerp (transform .rotation ,quaternion, Time.
               deltaTime * movoement * rotateSpeed);
               transform.rotation = targetRotation;                                                             
               #endregion
               

               #region Movement
               float speed = runSpeed;
               moveType = 2;
               if (playerinput.sprint)
               {
                  speed = sprintSpeed;
                  moveType = 3;

               }
               else if (playerinput.Walk)
               {
                  speed = walkSpeed;
                  moveType = 1;
               }
               if (crouched)
               {
                  speed = crouchWalkSpeed;
               }
               Vector3 targetPosition = transform.forward * movement * speed / 100;
               targetPosition.y = 0;
               transform.Translate(targetPosition, Space.World);
               #endregion

           }

       }
       else
       {

     }
  }

}
```

Player weapon:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerWeapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Weapon weapon = null;
    private playerLocomotion playerLocomotion = null;
    playerAnimation playerAnimation = null;
    playerCamera playerCamera = null;
    public float moveSpeed = 10;
    public float rotateSpeed = 10;
    private Weapon.Pose pose = Weapon.Pose.stndingNormal;
    public Weapon.Properties.Pose poseData = new Weapon.Properties.Pose();

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerCamera = GetComponent<playerCamera>();
        playerAnimation = GetComponent<playerAnimation>();
        playerLocomotion = GetComponent<playerLocomotion>();

    }
    
    private void Satart()
    {
        if (weapon)
        {
            Initialize();
        }     
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        Initialize(Vector3.zero);
    }

    public void Initialize(Vector3 zero)
    {
        weapon.transform.parent = GetComponent<Animator>().GetBoneTransform(HumanBodyBones.Chest);
        weapon.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        weapon.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
        poseData = weapon.GetPose(pose);
        weapon.model.localPosition = poseData.pose.position;
        weapon.model.localRotation = poseData.pose.rotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!weapon)
        { 
          return;
        }
        if (playerLocomotion.crouched)
        {
            if (playerLocomotion.aiming)
            {
              pose = Weapon.Pose.crouchedAimed;
            }
            else
            {
              pose = Weapon.Pose.crouchedNormal;
            }    
            
        }
        else
        {
           if (playerLocomotion.aiming)
            { 
              pose = Weapon.Pose.standingAimed;
            }
            else
            {
              pose = Weapon.Pose.stndingNormal;
            } 
        }
        poseData = weapon.GetPose(pose);
        if(weapon.model.position != poseData.pose.position)
        {
          weapon.model.position = Vector3.Lerp(weapon.model.position, poseData.pose.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if(weapon.model.rotation != poseData.pose.rotation)
        {
          weapon.model.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(weapon.model.rotation, poseData.pose.rotation, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I understood you, but I tried it

Answer (score 2):

In the class playerWeapon, you have this method:

```
private void Satart()
```

I think this is supposed to mean `Start`. The Start method gets executed automatically on the first frame of the objects existence, but you have to spell it correctly. When you misspell a Unity event method, then it won't get recognized by the engine and the engine won't call it.

The result is that `Initialize` won't get called either, which means that the weapon model never gets parented to the armature of the character.

I don't know what IDE you are using for editing your code, but I would recommend Visual Studio 2019. When you create a Unity event method, then it will show a small Unity-icon above it. When you misspell the method name, then that icon won't show up and you get a warning instead telling you you created a private method which is not used anywhere.

---

The warnings you receive about unused variables appear to be unrelated to this particular problem. I would assume that you were told to create those variables in preparation of features which come later in the tutorial you are following.

Although if your character has a problem with aiming at things you are pointing at, then the first one "`playerAnimation.aimMask` is never assigned to" might be worth investigating. The value is later used in the method `GetAimTarget` to determine what colliders are considered valid objects to aim at via [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).

Comment: I understood you, but I tried it